# how to align an arrow head to the center of a snaked line

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to generate a snaked line with an arrow head at the end of the line, I can use the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=snake] % used for wavy arrows
\draw[>=stealth, ->, snake=snake,segment amplitude = .4mm, segment length = 2mm] (1.5,6.5) -- (0,9.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the placement of the arrowhead does not look correct  in the sense that it is not in the center at the end of the line. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can give a little room for the arrowhead computation by terminating the decoration a little earlier using `post length` key.

Also `snake` library is now obsolete and part of the `decorations.pathmorphing` library. So better switch to that or update your TikZ distribution if it's still the older version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-stealth,
decoration={snake, 
    amplitude = .4mm,
    segment length = 2mm,
    post length=0.9mm},decorate] (1.5,6.5) -- (0,9.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]