# TikZ: correct position for arrowhead when using partway modifiers

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

My question is a more complicated case [of this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100540/how-to-align-an-arrow-head-to-the-center-of-a-snaked-line). I am trying to make the arrowhead of an arrow decorated with snake be well-centered, but using the solution suggested in the other question causes the arrowhead to be completely separated from its arrow and put onto the other arrow. This is obviously due to the relative/partway coordinates. How do I solve this problem?

Here is a MWE with the described behavior:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix,arrows,snakes,shapes,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, auto, >=latex]

\node[draw, rectangle] (11cR) {11-\textit{cis}-ret.};
\node[draw, rectangle] (atR) [below of=11cR] {all-\textit{trans}-ret.} edge [<-] (11cR);

\draw[<-, decorate, decoration={snake, post length=0.9mm}] ($(11cR.south)!0.5!(atR.north)$) -- ++(-2.2cm,-1.2cm) node[below] {$h\nu$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Changing the value of `post length` didn't help either.

[image: head–arrow separation in TikZ]

Comment: `post length` is for the end of the path. Here you have to also modify the start with `pre length=2mm` or invert the path. Partway coordinates are as good as other coordinates and not related to the path drawings. I'm guessing but I think you also have TikZ v2.10 still but not 3.00

Comment: Of course I didn't think about that. I'll try it out once I'm back to the computer, but it seems like the obvious solution to the problem. Still a weird behavior of TikZ to respond by "merging" the arrows IMHO.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. @percusse, do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it or is the question not worth keeping?